# Python global variable referenced before assigned a value

Tags: c#, python

I recently started to program in python, and I love it so far. I previously programmed in c# and java, which is probably causing my problem. In c#, if you have a public variable, it will change in each method. Sorry for the bad explanation, but it will be easier to visualize the code.

This code is an example of what I want to happen in python in c# form. The code does not actually work because it's only an example.

```
class Player
{
    public var player; //create the variable
    public var playerRectangle;
    public var playerMovement;

    public Player()
    {
        player = pygame.image.load("player.png"); //set the variables value
        playerRectangle = player.get_rect();

        playerMovement = new int[0,0];
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMovement[1] = -2   //use the variables value
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMovement[1] = 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = -2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 2

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMovement[1] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMovement[1] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 0

        playerRectangle = playerRectangle.move(playerMovement)
    }
}
```

The actual python code is:

```
import pygame

class Player:
    player = None #create the variable
    playerRectangle = None
    playerMovement = None

    def __init__():
        global player
        player = pygame.image.load("player.png") #set the variables value
        global playerRectangle
        playerRectangle = player.get_rect()

        global playerMovement
        playerMovement = [0,0]

    def update():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMovement[1] = -2 #use the variables !!ERROR!!
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMovement[1] = 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = -2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 2

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerMovement[1] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerMovement[1] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 0

        playerRectangle = playerRectangle.move(playerMovement)

    def returnTexture():
        return player

    def returnRectangle():
        return playerRectangle
```

It says that the variable is referenced before it was given a value, but I gave it a value in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten (*or have not read*) the use of `self` in your methods.

You need to put `self` in the method definitions
and use `self.<attribute>` to reference attributes on the instance.

**Example:**

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def update_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

bob = Player("Bob")
print bob.name  # Bob

bob.update_name("Bob Jones")
print bob.name  # Bob Jones
```

**Note:** That the use of `self` in method definitions of classes in Python is by convention only; you can use whatever name you like but we widely and typically (*by convention*) use `self`.

See: [Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

See Also: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

**Side Note:** One of the reasons for this (*btw*) is that in Python we like to be more explicit about how we write code. See the 2nd line of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
>
> ```
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> ...
> ```

**Update:** It's also worth nothing (*please read the documentation*) that there is no notion of public vs. private members with Python's type system. We define "private" members by convention only usually with a prefixed single underscore; e.g: `def _foo(self):` as a private/inernal method.